How to invoke DLL from the Global Assembly Cache by VS2019?
I create one library project and using sn tool to create one snk file. And sign it by as generally like below.

Then I used the following command to add the file Joeylib.dll to the Global Assembly Cache (GAC)
gacutil.exe -i c:\\Joeylib.dll

I create another project as winform, and add the reference from c:\Joeylib.dll.
Everything looks smooth and it can runing. But when I remove the file Joeylib.dll from bin folder then clicking the Exe file to run winform program, it failed to work, and says cannot find the Joeylib.dll.
what my expection is automatically to invoke GAC DLL. Do I miss some steps?
BTW, I also add the reference information in csproj file
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Joeylib, Version=2.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=75243be5df0ddea9, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>import\Joeylib.dll</HintPath>
      <SpecificVersion>false</SpecificVersion>
      <Private>false</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

I expect it can invoke dll from GAC automatically when I delete the dll from bin folder
